# Packet ByteBuffer to generic packet

Tags: java, sockets, arrays, packet

I currently have the following code to decode an ip packet from a `ByteBuffer`

```
    int buffer = packet.get();
    int headerlength;
    int temp;

    version = buffer >> 4;
    headerlength = buffer & 0x0F;
    headerlength *= 4;
    System.out.println("IP Version:" + version);
    System.out.println("Header Length:" + headerlength);
    String status = "";
    status += "Header Length:" + headerlength;

    buffer = packet.get();      //DSCP + EN
    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Total Length

    System.out.println("Total Length:" + buffer);

    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Identification
    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Flags + Fragment Offset
    buffer = packet.get();      //Time to Live
    buffer = packet.get();      //Protocol

    protocol = buffer;
    System.out.println("Protocol:" + buffer);

    status += "  Protocol:" + buffer;

    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Header checksum


    byte buff = (byte) buffer;

    sourceIP = "";
    buff = packet.get();  //Source IP 1st Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    sourceIP += temp;
    sourceIP += ".";

    buff = packet.get();  //Source IP 2nd Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    sourceIP += temp;
    sourceIP += ".";

    buff = packet.get();  //Source IP 3rd Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    sourceIP += temp;
    sourceIP += ".";

    buff = packet.get();  //Source IP 4th Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    sourceIP += temp;

    System.out.println("Source IP:" + sourceIP);

    status += "   Source IP:" + sourceIP;


    destIP = "";


    buff = packet.get();  //Destination IP 1st Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    destIP += temp;
    destIP += ".";

    buff = packet.get();  //Destination IP 2nd Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    destIP += temp;
    destIP += ".";

    buff = packet.get();  //Destination IP 3rd Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    destIP += temp;
    destIP += ".";

    buff = packet.get();  //Destination IP 4th Octet
    temp = ((int) buff) & 0xFF;
    destIP += temp;
```

It resolves the hostname, destination ip, source ip, version, protocol and port but I want to have all the content of the packet.

I didn't write this code myself so I dont completely understand it. what i do understand that the different bits in the `ByteArray packet` contain different data depending on the position of the bit. Only problem is I don't know how to retrieve the data using that logic.

Comment: Is this an *IP* packet? Very little information provided in this question. Not enough. NB `getChar()` should certainly be `getUnsignedShort()` throughout.

Comment: Yes it is an ip packet

Comment: Well what's the problem? Read to the end of the header, if you haven't already done so: you already have the length; just read that many bytes.